# Python Script to printscreen execution of prompt commands

Tags: python

I'm building a python script to a college work, that it executes some prompt commands and save a screenshot of the execution, but i'm having trouble with clearing the screen(clear/cls) between every screenshot (to look cleaner)
here's my script:

```
import pyautogui
import subprocess
import time

comands_list = open('comandos.txt').read().splitlines()

for i in range(len(comands_list)):
    comando = comands_list[i]
    print("Comando executado: " + comando)
    s = subprocess.getstatusoutput(comando)
    print("Resultado da execução: \n" + s[1])
    try:
        myScreenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
        myScreenshot.save(comando+'.png')
        print("Captura de tela salva com sucesso!")
    except:
        print("Captura de tela não salva!")
    subprocess.getoutput("clear")
    #time.sleep(3)
```

**Any help is welcome, thanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clear the python outputs, do something like this:
(Note, this does not work for IDLE python shell, you should just double click on the python program to execute it)

```
import pyautogui
import subprocess
import time
import os
clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
commands = ["echo hi", "echo hello"]
for i in range(len(commands)):
    c = commands[i]
    s = subprocess.getstatusoutput(c)
    print(s)
    try:
        screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
        screenshot.save(str(i+1)+'.png')
        print("Success")
    except:
        print("Error")
    subprocess.getoutput("CLS")
    time.sleep(3)
    clear()
```

Comment: I know, but it dont clear the terminal if its being executed from the script, thats the issue